# how can i remove these spaces between buttons? python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

is there a way to remove these spaces between the buttons?

https://imgur.com/IdwAgDX

```py
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=2)
list1.grid(row=1, column=2)
lbl2.grid(row=0, column=3)
list2.grid(row=1, column=3)
lbl3.grid(row=0, column=4)
list3.grid(row=1, column=4)
bt0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="W")
bt1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
bt2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="W")
bt3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="W")
bt4.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="W")
bt5.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="W")
```

Comment: if you put high element in cell then all cells in this row will have space around - like in `Excel`. But Inside cell you can put `Frame` and use `pack()/grid()` to put `Buttons` in this frame. Using `Frames` you can mix `grid()` with `pack()` and with other `grid()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `Frame` in cell and use `pack()` or `grid()` to put buttons in this frame

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

f0 = tk.Frame(root)
f0.grid(row=0, column=1)

bA = tk.Button(f0, text='Button A')
bA.pack(side='left')

bB = tk.Button(f0, text='Button B')
bB.pack(side='left')

bB = tk.Button(f0, text='Button C')
bB.pack(side='left')

f1 = tk.Frame(root)
f1.grid(row=1, column=0)

b1 = tk.Button(f1, text='Button 1')
b1.pack()

b2 = tk.Button(f1, text='Button 2')
b2.pack()

b3 = tk.Button(f1, text='Button 3')
b3.pack()

t1 = tk.Text(root)
t1.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: enter code here]

---

Or you can use `rowspan` so widget (ie. `Text`) will use many rows and then other widgets will use less space - but still there will be some space around buttons. If you also use `rowconfig(... ,weight=1)` then last row will use all free space.

I have 3 rows with buttons but I use `rowspan=4` so `Text` will also use empty row after buttons. And then I use `root.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)` so this empty row will use all emtpy space in column.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

bA = tk.Button(root, text='Button A')
bA.grid(row=0, column=1)

bB = tk.Button(root, text='Button B')
bB.grid(row=0, column=2)

bC = tk.Button(root, text='Button C')
bC.grid(row=0, column=3)

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 1')
b1.grid(row=1, column=0)

b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 2')
b2.grid(row=2, column=0)

b3 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 3')
b3.grid(row=3, column=0)

t1 = tk.Text(root)
t1.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=4, columnspan=4)

root.rowconfigure(4, weight=1) # resize

root.columnconfigure(4, weight=1) # resize

root.mainloop()
```

[image]